# Python: class not callable from separate file?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a class, robot, in a file called robot.py

I want to create a robot instance in my main script like so:

in robot.py:

```
class robot(object):
    def __init__(self,pygame,screen_width,screen_height):
```

in main.py:

```
import pygame, sys, copy
import mouse
import robot
import menu
import button
from pygame.locals import *
...
size = [1200,900]
my_robot = robot(pygame,size[0]-400,size[1]-100)
```

error:

```
me:cup-robot Me$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 24, in <module>
    my_robot = robot(pygame,size[0]-400,size[1]-100)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

how do I do this?

Comment: `from robot import robot`?

Comment: #protip: don't name your class the same as your method ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two choices :

`import robot` and then prefix all with robot :

```
my_robot = robot.robot(pygame,size[0]-400,size[1]-100)
```

or

`from robot import robot` and then your code should work. But then, you can see that you won't be able to distinguish if robot is a module or the class, so you should not name the class and the file with the same name.

Answer (score 6):

Change your import statement:

```
from robot import robot
```

You have `robot` defined both as a module (robot.py) as well as a class.  You need to import the class from the module so it is publicly available.